# Vlookup help finding closest date after reference date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Hi I need help filling out the highlighted colum. The goal here is to fill out in Sheet 1, Column C "Closest After Dates in B", with the closet date after column B "Date signed up" by vlooking up to sheet 2 column B "Time", with criteria that Type is either "email", "outbound" or "inbound". I am doing this in google sheets not excel! Thank you for all your help.

[image]

I tried doing vlookup + index match, but really not fully versed in how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `QUERY()` function in google-sheet. Try-

`=QUERY($F$2:$H,"select G where F='" & A2 & "' and G>= datetime '" & TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "' and H matches 'Email|Inbound|Outbound' order by G limit 1")`

[image]

Comment: I have a similar question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945717/vlookup-help-finding-person-that-is-closest-date-after-reference-date), can you help?

Comment: Same formula should work. Did you tried it. Share a sample google-sheet.