# Vlookup help finding person that is closest date after reference date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I need help filling out the highlighted column. The goal here is to fill out in Sheet 1, Column D "1st Agent To Call", with the closet date after column C "Task Date" by vlooking up to sheet 2 column H "Task Done At", with Column J "Criteria" has to be "inbound" or "outbound"  The highlighted in Yellow is the correct answer as an example. I had asked a similar question and answer worked using query so need help to modify the query [function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610455/vlookup-help-finding-closest-date-after-reference-date/75610752#75610752)

[image: here's my terrible example]

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: Build a filter for the difference between dates, then get the minimum. [Click here](https://youtu.be/X8PyTo6NyXA?t=6) to see how much work you should have to exert.